# Update table ONLY when specific values are not already contained in any row in the table

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to update a table with PHP and MYSQLi in the following way:
In the application, the user could create new categories and each category should be unique such that at the time of creating the category, the values for `$category_title` **OR** `$category_price` **OR** `$category_limit` does not already exist in their corresponding fields in the database. (I have already done this)

Now, assuming a user has created these categories where each category has a price and the number of items each category could contain:

```
Category Title      |     Price     |  Limit
-------------------------------------------- 
English             |     $5.00     |   100 
French              |     $3.00     |   200 
Latin               |     $10.00    |   300
```

The user now needs to edit the `French Category`. However, he shouldn't be able to change the category's Title (***French** in this case*) to say, **English**, since English is already in the list.
OR, he should not be able to set Price to **$10.00** since that is the price for **Latin**.

This is my code for the UPDATE statement:

```
$check = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_title = '$category_title' OR cat_price = '$category_price' OR cat_limit = '$category_limit' AND cat_id != '$id'");
    if($check->num_rows !== 0){
        exit('Make sure Category Title, Limit or Price does not already exist');
} else {
    $update = $db->query("UPDATE categories SET cat_title = '$category_title', cat_price = '$category_price', cat_limit = '$category_limit' WHERE cat_id = '$id'");
}
```

The code above checks whether the values for **`$category_title`** or **`$category_price`** or **`$category_limit`** can be found anywhere in the table other than the category being edited.

How ever, it seems to disallow the user from updating the category even when there are no possible value duplicates in the table.

Example, if the user updates the price for **French** to **$150.56** based on the above category table, it returns `Make sure Category Title, Limit or Price does not already exist`.

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the parenthesis

```
SELECT * 
  FROM categories
 WHERE (cat_title = '$category_title' OR cat_price = '$category_price' OR cat_limit = '$category_limit')
   AND cat_id != '$id'
```

Now, all the `OR` conditions will be evaluated together, as the `AND` condition will prevail.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried this and still getting same results. Even when the user does not change anything and hit submit, it returns the same message. Or I'm I missing anything else?

Comment: The query compares title, price and limit. You really need to compare all of those columns or just the title?

Comment: I'm comparing all the 3 columns

Comment: Okay now it worked. I just didn't observe the position of the closing parenthesis in your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply want unique constraints/indexes.  You can create them as:

```
create unique index unq_categories_title on categories(title);
create unique index unq_categories_price on categories(price);
```

The *database* will enforce the data integrity checks, not allowing new rows or updated rows to repeat values in these columns.

This is usually a much better approach than using application logic.  For instance, two users could insert the same row at about the same time -- when the check is in the application.  With a database constraint, the database guarantees uniqueness.

Comment: Nice tip. Still, will throw an error to the user. The OP should do this to avoid database inconsistency, and improve the query to show the error to the user.

Comment: Okay Gordon, I suppose after creating the unique indexes, i don't have to do a check before updating?

Comment: @OforiKingsford . . . No, you do not.  You may want to check if the `insert` or `update` fails.